# Is it possible to shorten a chain?

Tags: chain, gears, single-speed

I have the following chain/gear setup:
[image]

I like to get rid of the rear wheel gears. However I don't want to buy any new parts. That is why I am wondering if I simply can remove all the parts from the rear gear shift, and simply shorten the chain?

Comment: Not if you plan to use your front derailleur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO

The derailleur holds chain tension.

At a minimum your would need a chain tensioner.
And it would need to line up with A gear.

Single speed and fixie have horizontal dropout to adjust tension.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have vertical dropouts, you'll need some sort of chain tensioner. You can buy one, or you can use the existing rear derailleur. You'll have to rig it up somehow so it stays in the same position (that is, so it's always lined up with the sprocket).

I strongly suggest reading [Sheldon Brown's article on single-speed conversions.](http://sheldonbrown.com/singlespeed.html)

[image]